# Read the spindle speed in a SIEMENS PLC s7 300 with python snap7

Tags: plc, siemens, snap7

I would like to read the spindle speed of a Siemens PLC 317-2DP with NCU 720.2.

To do that, I use the python snap 7 library.
I managed the connexion to the PLC, but I would like to read the spindle speed with the function `read_area(area: Areas, dbnumber: int, start: int, size: int)`.
I am unable to find the parameters dbNumber, start and size for my case.

Does someone can help me please? I read that it depends of the configuration of the PLC, but where I can find this configuration?

Thanks for your help

I read the documentation from Siemens "SINUMERIK 840D sl
NC variables and interface signals" but I didn't find what I needed...

Comment: first of all do you have a db with this information? if you have the information in  a DB you have to check if the db attribute is marked as optimized or not, optimized dbs cannot be read with snap7

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't understand that the PLC needeat to be set in order to give DB adresses to the required parameters. I thought that the variables would be directly accessible, that's why we wasn't able to find the spindle speed's DB address...

Answer (score 0):

In general in order to access to a variable in the plc you need to have a db block as I previously mentioned in one of my comments, but one important thing is to marked this block as not optimized:

[image: Optimized block access off]

if you have created this db an you recently added new variables a compile is needed to recalculate the offset in the variables. If you perform these steps successfully you will be able to see the offsets like in the following image:

[image: variable offsets]

I post this information as an answer for people that need that information in the future.

Regards

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more information to the answer, in the case of the S300 they are not able to mark the optimized block access (At least in my case a S313-2 DP)